# Cordova: pause event fires randomly on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've set some action which fires on 'pause' event in a cordova project so it should execute when the app goes to background. What's strange on Android this event sometimes fires randomly while I'm using the app. I've tried to use the 'resume' event but the situation is the same. On iOS it works perfectly. Any ideas what could be the issue here?

I'm working on Cordova 4.3.0, testing on Samsung Galaxy Tab S with Android 4.4.2.
In this project I also use Ionic Framework 1.3.13 (if it does matter).

Comment: Could you find the reason for this?

Comment: I haven't found any. The only reasonable explanation that I've came up so far is that this bug is specific for this particular device. I couldn't reproduce it on my other Andorid devices - Galaxy Tab 2 & Galaxy Tab 4.